# Google Dialogflow Translation

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

Hi I am trying to write a bot that translate whatever user write into Finnish. 
I have configured the default fallback intent that take whatever the user say and translated it, but it does not work

```
function translateStuff(input){
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    googleTranslate.translate(input, 'eng', function(err, translation) {
        if (err !== null) reject(err);
        else resolve(translation.translatedText);
    });
});
```

}

```
function fallback(agent) {
var userInput = agent.query;
translateStuff('kuka sina olet').then(function(value) {
  agent.add(value);
});
```

}

But the fallback function does not return the translated text, does any one know what is the problem. Thank you

Comment: convert your callback in promise and return

Comment: I have changed it to function, but it still not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

function handlers support promises now so you can return a promise and process things like http requests in the promise. Here is an example of using the request library:

```
function dialogflowHanlderWithRequest(agent) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request.get(options, (error, response, body) => {
      JSON.parse(body)
      // processing code
      agent.add(...)
      resolve();
    });
  });
};
```

You can also move the HTTP call to another function that returns a promise. Here is an example with the axios library:

```
function dialogflowHandlerWithAxios(agent) {
  return callApi('www.google.com').then(response => {
    agent.add('My response');
  }).catch (error => {
    // do something
  })
};

function callApi(url) {
    return axios.get(url);
}
```

Does this satisfy your use case? You just need to put your translate function in place